# Shell script with wc -l, if statement ain't working

Tags: bash, shell

The problem is with this code:

```
    words=`wc -l /home/tmp/logged.log | awk '{print $1}'`;
    if [ $words == 26 ]
    then
    echo $words
    echo Good
    else
    echo Not so good
    fi
```

it always returns the else statement. Even tho the result is 26.
I also tried

```
     words=`wc -l < /home/jonathan/tmp/logged.log`;
```

Comment: My bet is that `$words` has a ending newline `"26\n"`.

Comment: To prevent `wc` printing the filename, make it read from stdin: `words=$(wc -l < /home/tmp/logged.log)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try to use `[ $words -eq 26 ]` instead of `[ $words == 26 ]`

or `[ 26 == 26 ]` to check that statement works properly

Comment: Thanks for the help, I found the problem on my own after trying 26 == 26.
The problem was this lastlog | grep Never | wc -l > /tmp/logged.log.
The logfile contained 1 row with value 26.

Comment: glad! however you can use some of C-type operators in bash by using such expr [[ 26 == 26 ]]

Answer (score 3):

Because `==` is not valid. Use `=`

```
if [ $words = 26 ]
```

By the way you can use `cut` instead of `awk`.

```
wc -l /home/tmp/logged.log  | cut -f1 -d" "
```

Comment: His second example, wc -l < file, would be the proper way.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I found the problem on my own after trying 26 == 26.
The problem was this lastlog | grep Never | wc -l > /tmp/logged.log.
The logfile contained 1 row with value 26.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
words=`wc -l /home/tmp/logged.log | awk '{print $1}'`;
if test $words -eq 26; then
    echo $words
    echo Good
else
    echo Not so good
fi
```